# Meaning of fragment having its own lifecycle

Tags: android

Everywhere it is written that fragments have their own lifecycle . Also fragment life cycle depend on activity's lifecycle.What is the meaning of fragment's own lifecycle if it is dependent on activity's lifecycle?

Comment: a activity can have multiple fragment added so being dependent does not make they will have same lifecycle though

Comment: Read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all you need to understand what are lifecycle methods are and when are they called/invoked. Lifecycle methods are basically invoked at the different state of your Activty/Fragment. For example when you first launch your activity the following flow of events/methods are called depending upon the state of your activity. For example : When your activity is first launched OnCreate is called, when your activity is no longer visible then onStop is called. So basically you first need to learn at which state are these different activities called.Below is a great referential flowchart for the same.

***Activity lifecycle methods :***

[image]

***Fragment lifecycle methods :***

[image]

Now, when you create a fragment it is inflated into the activty. And it has its own set of lifecycle events/methods which are called and since the fragment is inflated into the activty when the state of your activity changes it effects the fragment and correspondingly different lifecycle methods of the fragments are called. Below is another pictorial representation of the relation between the lifecycle methods of the activity and the fragment.

[image]

Image source : Google Images

Answer (score 2):

The activity lifecycle is fairly simple in comparison to the fragment lolcycle (image from Square's Advocating against Android Fragments)

[image: The fragment lolcycle]